# How do I change the alignment of my search box?

Tags: css, alignment

How can I change the position of this search box to right-top and align it?

HTML

```
<form class="form-wrapper cf">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search here..." required>
  <button type="submit">Go</button>
</form>
```

CSS

```
.cf:before, .cf:after{
    content:"";
    display:table;
}
.cf:after{
    clear:both;
}
.cf{
    zoom:1;
}    
/* Form wrapper styling */
.form-wrapper {
    width: 450px;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 600px auto 50px auto;
    background: #444;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.4) inset, 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.2);
}
/* Form text input */
.form-wrapper input {
    width: 330px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    float: left;    
    font: bold 15px 'lucida sans', 'trebuchet MS', 'Tahoma';
    border: 0;
    background: #eee;
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;      
}
.form-wrapper input:focus {
    outline: 0;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.8) inset;
}
.form-wrapper input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: #999;
   font-weight: normal;
   font-style: italic;
}
.form-wrapper input:-moz-placeholder {
    color: #999;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: italic;
}
.form-wrapper input:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: #999;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: italic;
}
/* Form submit button */
.form-wrapper button {
    overflow: visible;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 40px;
    width: 110px;
    font: bold 15px/40px 'lucida sans', 'trebuchet MS', 'Tahoma';
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: #d83c3c;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;      
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0 ,0, .3);
}   
.form-wrapper button:hover{     
    background: #e54040;
}   
.form-wrapper button:active,
.form-wrapper button:focus{   
    background: #c42f2f;
    outline: 0;   
}
.form-wrapper button:before { /* left arrow */
    content: '';
    border-width: 8px 8px 8px 0;
    border-style: solid solid solid none;
    border-color: transparent #d83c3c transparent;
    top: 12px;
    left: -6px;
}
.form-wrapper button:hover:before{
    border-right-color: #e54040;
}
.form-wrapper button:focus:before,
.form-wrapper button:active:before{
        border-right-color: #c42f2f;
}      
.form-wrapper button::-moz-focus-inner { /* remove extra button spacing for Mozilla      Firefox */
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a quite big example and broad question. I suggest adding a fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Close the button tag
2. You've floated both the search bar and
   the button. The parent div won't use the height that the children
   occupy, until you insert a div with style "clear:both". You've done
   a "clear: both" after the form, and not after the children.

   ```
   <form class="form-wrapper cf">       
       <input type="text" placeholder="Search here..." required>  
       <button type="submit">Go< /button>< div style="clear:both">  
       </div>  
   </form>
   ```

With respect to aligning it to right top, you need to position it absolute or fixed, and specify the "right" and "top" attributes. Did you even try doing that? Or, did you think that you could copy a snippet from somewhere and Stackoverflow members would fix it for you?

```
.form-wrapper {
    width: 450px;
    padding: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    top:50px;
    right: 50px;
    background: #444;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.4) inset, 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.2);
}
```

Here is the fixed code - http://jsfiddle.net/a2ev8/2/

Comment: Reduce the 'top' attribute's value(say 20px or 30px instead of 50px) to move it higher. Please learn some basic CSS. You would have been flamed for not doing your research, if it were a typical IRC channel.